# How to get returned result from function in Task.Run(Xamarin.Android)?

Tags: xamarin.android, task, progressdialog

I have the following views in my activity:

```
private Button btn;
private TextView txtView;
```

I have the following button click event:

```
private async void Btn_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     var mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
     mDialog.SetMessage("Loading data...");
     mDialog.SetCancelable(false);
     mDialog.Show();

     string str;

     await Task.Run((() => str = Foo()));
     // Alternatively
     // await Task.Delay(10000);

     mDialog.Dismiss();

     txtView.Text = str;


}
```

And I also have the following method:

```
string Foo()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    return "hello";
}
```

What I want is `txtView.Text` to be set to `hello` after the `ProgressDialog` is dismissed

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

`Task.Run` is not meant to be used like that what it does is Queues the specified work to run on the ThreadPool and returns a task or `Task<TResult>` handle for that work.

What you should do is make a method with a return type of `Task<string>` and then await that method

Then use that method to update your textview data

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

You can set a dismiss listener by using `SetOnDismissListener` to do some work after  the `ProgressDialog` is dismissed.

First, let your activity inherit from `IDialogInterfaceOnDismissListener`:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, IDialogInterfaceOnDismissListener
```

In your button click event, set your `activity` as the `listener`:

```
        private async void Btn_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mDialog.SetMessage("Loading data...");
        mDialog.SetCancelable(false);

        //set your activity as the listener
        mDialog.SetOnDismissListener(this);

        mDialog.Show();
        await Task.Delay(10000);
        mDialog.Dismiss();

    }
```

Then you should implement the interface(`IDialogInterfaceOnDismissListener`) member `OnDismiss`, in this function, you can do whatever you want to do after the ProgressDialog is dismissed:

```
public void OnDismiss(IDialogInterface dialog)
{

    Toast.MakeText(this, "You used the 'SetOnDismissListener'.", ToastLength.Long).Show();

    txtView.Text = "hello";
}
```

You can refer:

[IDialogInterfaceOnDismissListener](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Dialog.SetOnDismissListener/p/Android.Content.IDialogInterfaceOnDismissListener/)

[using-setondismisslistener-with-dialog](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/13061/using-setondismisslistener-with-dialog)